# Using unravel_index to find the index of a largest number

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the numpy function

```
unravel_index
```

by applying it to find the index for the largest number in an n-dimensional array. I could always find the largest number using the following call:

```
np.where(a == a.max())[0][0]
```

I am trying to use `unravel_index` in the following fashion:

```
a.unravel_index([a.max()],a.shape)
```

but this does not work. How could I use `unravel_index` to find the index of the largest number?

Comment: IIUC, you need to unravel **index**, not the max value itself. So, `a.unravel_index(np.where(a == a.max())[0][0],a.shape)` may be what you want.

Comment: What is the shape of your array and do you want a flat index or a 2D, 3D etc. index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) converts a flat index into a dimensional index. Thus you need to pass a flat index to `np.unravel_index` as well as the shape of the array. A flat index is the index to an array cell, if you transform (view) a multi-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array/vector.

For your case, you probably want to use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the flat index and then use `np.unravel_index` to get the dimensional index (if needed):

```
a = np.random.rand(100, 100)
flat_idx = a.argmax()
dim_idx = np.unravel_index(flat_idx, a.shape)
```

To return the max. value, you can now use both to index the array `a`:

```
print(a.flat[flat_idx])
print(a[dim_idx])
```

Using `np.where` with indexing the first element with `[0][0]` will **only work with one-dimensional arrays!**
If call it without indexing the first element, it will return quite much the same as `np.unravel_index`. But while `np.unravel_index` returns a `tuple` of integeres, `np.where` will return a `tuple` of integer arrays.
This makes indexing AND finding the indices alot slower! `np.where(a == a.max())` takes about **4 times longer** than `np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)`. (Tested for arrays of shape (100,100) and (1000,1000).)